# Perl open file problem

Tags: perl, cgi

I am having some trouble trying to print from a file. Any ideas? Thanks

```
open(STDOUT,">/home/int420_101a05/shttpd/htdocs/receipt.html"); 
#Results of a sub-routine
&printReceipt; 
close(STDOUT);

open(INF,"/home/int420_101a05/shttpd/htdocs/receipt.html"); $emailBody = <INF>; 
close(INF); 
print $emailBody;

ERRORS: Filehandle STDOUT reopened as INF only for input at ./test.c line 6. 
print() on closed filehandle STDOUT at ./test.c line 9.
```

Comment: It looks like you don't need the temp file if you're just going to print it to STDOUT anyway.

Comment: @brian - good point based on the skeleton code above. I'm guessing the second block is just for logging/verification, the main goal is to get `receipt.html` on disk. alex - could you please clarify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. [This discussion addresses the technical reason for the message](http://groups.google.com/group/perl.perl5.porters/browse_thread/thread/4d550adeddf6f6c7/1840fa35819a10b8?lnk=st&q=reopened+"only+for+input"+group%3A*perl*&rnum=7&hl=en&pli=1). Relevant info from the thread is this:

   From open(2) manpage:

   When the call is successful, the file descriptor returned will be
   the lowest file descriptor not currently open for the process.

   > But STDOUT still refers to the
   >   filehandle #1. This warning could be
   >   useful. Although one can argue that
   >   further uses of STDOUT as an output
   >   filehandle will trigger a warning as
   >   well...

   So, to summarize, you closed STDOUT (file descriptor 1) and your file will be open as FD#1. That's due to `open()'s` properties.
2. As other have noted, the real reason you're having this problem is that you should not use STDOUT for printing to a file unless there's some special case where it's required.

   Instead, open a file for writing using a new file handle:

   ```
   open(OUTFILE,">/home/int420_101a05/shttpd/htdocs/receipt.html")
      || die "Could not open: $!"; 
   print OUTFILE "data";
   close(OUTFILE);
   ```
3. **To print to filehandle from subroutine, just pass the file handle as a parameter**.

   The best way of doing so is to create an `IO::File` object and pass that object around

   ```
   my $filehandle = IO::File->new(">$filename") || die "error: $!";
   mySub($filehandle);

   sub mySub {
    my $fh = shift;
    print $fh "stuff" || die "could not print $!";    
   }
   ```

   You can also set a particular filehandle as a default filehandle to have print print to that by default using `select` but that is a LOT more fragile and should be avoidded in favor of IO::File solution.

Comment: The thing is that i want to print the results of a subroutine... is there any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: What you want to do is `select FILEHANDLE`. The `select` call sets a new filehandle as the default destination for print calls.

Comment: @alexBrand - Added the info on how to print properly in a subroutine

Answer (score 1):

If you want to temporarily change the standard output, use the [select](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) builtin. Another option is to localize the typeglob first:

```
{
    local *STDOUT;
    open STDOUT, '>', 'outfile.txt' or die $!;
    print "Sent to file\n";
}
```

Comment: The thing is i am trying to print the results of a subroutine to the file... I just changed the code.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to open the STDOUT handle. If you want to print to STDOUT, just use `print` (with no filehandle argument). If you want to print to something other than STDOUT, use a different name.